# Finding a line intersection

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the following list of rational functions:

```
l={(1.92593 x + 156.713 x^2 + 984.928 x^3 + 2835.89 x^4 + 4790.17 x^5 + 
    6312.74 x^6 + 6361.5 x^7 + 4893.32 x^8 + 2894.32 x^9 + 
    1291.06 x^10 + 408.032 x^11 + 92.1898 x^12 + 16.5306 x^13 + 
    2.35827 x^14)/(x + 140 x^2 + 1006 x^3 + 3127 x^4 + 5556 x^5 + 
    7697 x^6 + 8277 x^7 + 6776 x^8 + 4316 x^9 + 2079 x^10 + 
    715 x^11 + 191 x^12 + 34 x^13 + 4 x^14), (0.962963 x + 
    153.004 x^2 + 1011.72 x^3 + 2964.87 x^4 + 4935.08 x^5 + 
    6585.44 x^6 + 6458.25 x^7 + 4863.74 x^8 + 2672.89 x^9 + 
    1103.88 x^10 + 311.636 x^11 + 69.3013 x^12 + 10.4081 x^13 + 
    1.17914 x^14)/(x + 140 x^2 + 1006 x^3 + 3127 x^4 + 5556 x^5 + 
    7697 x^6 + 8277 x^7 + 6776 x^8 + 4316 x^9 + 2079 x^10 + 
    715 x^11 + 191 x^12 + 34 x^13 + 4 x^14), (3.85185 x + 
    151.15 x^2 + 1008.14 x^3 + 2935.63 x^4 + 4950.81 x^5 + 
    6367.76 x^6 + 6316.97 x^7 + 4809.03 x^8 + 2847.33 x^9 + 
    1204.67 x^10 + 389.545 x^11 + 90.9182 x^12 + 12.8571 x^13 + 
    1.76871 x^14)/(x + 140 x^2 + 1006 x^3 + 3127 x^4 + 5556 x^5 + 
    7697 x^6 + 8277 x^7 + 6776 x^8 + 4316 x^9 + 2079 x^10 + 
    715 x^11 + 191 x^12 + 34 x^13 + 4 x^14), (0.962963 x + 
    153.004 x^2 + 1192.99 x^3 + 3370.73 x^4 + 5298.59 x^5 + 
    6738.54 x^6 + 6391.45 x^7 + 4497.74 x^8 + 2426.53 x^9 + 
    924.928 x^10 + 264.098 x^11 + 45.1412 x^12 + 6.12244 x^13 + 
    1.17914 x^14)/(x + 140 x^2 + 1006 x^3 + 3127 x^4 + 5556 x^5 + 
    7697 x^6 + 8277 x^7 + 6776 x^8 + 4316 x^9 + 2079 x^10 + 
    715 x^11 + 191 x^12 + 34 x^13 + 4 x^14), (1.92593 x + 
    142.804 x^2 + 957.246 x^3 + 2757.64 x^4 + 4703.23 x^5 + 
    6194.73 x^6 + 6419.86 x^7 + 4933.98 x^8 + 2976.2 x^9 + 
    1339.05 x^10 + 437.082 x^11 + 109.356 x^12 + 18.9796 x^13 + 
    1.76871 x^14)/(x + 140 x^2 + 1006 x^3 + 3127 x^4 + 5556 x^5 + 
    7697 x^6 + 8277 x^7 + 6776 x^8 + 4316 x^9 + 2079 x^10 + 
    715 x^11 + 191 x^12 + 34 x^13 + 4 x^14)}
```

I would plot them between `0<x<1` using:

```
Plot[{1, l}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

which would give:

[image]

How can I list the value of `x`'s at which `y=1`?

Comment: `x/.FindInstance[#==1,x,Reals,2]&/@l` Finds at most two crossings since some of the lines appear to cross y=1 more than once.

Comment: Also you can just `NSolve[ #==1 && 0<x<1 ] & /@ l` and you will find numerically all the solutions to the equation $f_i(x)=1$ with $0<x<1$.

Comment: Also `FindRoot[# == 1, {x, 0.4}] & /@ l`.

Answer (score 3):

Using dpravos comment:

```
sol = x /. NSolve[# == 1 && 0 < x < 1] & /@ l // Flatten
```

{0.188081, 0.00284485, 0.200019, 0.233586, 0.0027398, 0.470394,
0.110004}

```
Plot[{1, l}, {x, 0, 1},
 Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[Medium], 
   Point /@ Partition[Riffle[sol, 1.0, {2, -1, 2}], 2]},
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[l, {x, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{1}}, 
 MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[6], 
 GridLines -> {None, {{1, Directive@{Thick, Dashed}}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just variant:

```
p = {x, 1} /. FindRoot[# - 1, {x, 0.3}] & /@ l
Plot[l, {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point@p}, 
 GridLines -> {None, {1}}]
```

Roots:

> {{0.188081, 1}, {0.200019, 1}, {0.233586, 1}, {0.470394,    1},
> {0.110004, 1}}

[image]